# Nested VPN connections

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn

I'm a molecular biologist that's taken on the role of bioinformatics and system admin for a small bioinformatics server at my university. I'm trying to remotely transfer data between two servers at different institutions, to access either server you have to be connected to that institutions VPN.

I attempted a test run(with my desktop) where I connected to the VPN at my institution and opened an SSH connection. In that SSH connection I attempted to connect my desktop to the VPN of the other institution. This froze the system and forced me to perform a hard reboot. Normally I can solve the issues by with some google searches, but all the results I see are skewed toward commercial VPN's. Is there a way to make this transfer happen remotely?

All the systems are running Ubuntu 18.04